# while using script in unix how can I get the bell to chime more than once

Tags: unix

I am writing a shell script and need the bell to chime several times. Is there a command variation or argument to make this happen ?

I have used the `\a` and the `\007` and I get one chime.  I can't seem to find how to make it happen more than once.

Comment: This seems related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109379/why-does-the-bell-character-have-a-limit

Answer (score 1):

run your beep command once, wait a second with sleep and run it again

for instance

```
echo -n $'\a' ; sleep 1; echo -n $'\a'
```

Comment: Is there a definite reason why the bel cannot happen in quick succession?